# How to get data from an API in a Angular Service and store it to be used by anyone in the future

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

This is more of a writing clean code/ optimizing existing code. 
I am writing my Angular Services to fetch data from backend like this

```
angular.module('myApp').service('Auth', ['$http', '$q', 'Config', function($http, $q, Config) {
    this.getUser = function() {
        return $http.get(Config.apiurl + '/auth/user')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                return $q.reject(error.data);
            });
    };
}]);
```

Now in this, I am calling getUser function n number of times from the Database. 
Now the question is, **is it okay to call this service to get n times redundant data or I should it be saved somewhere say rootscope to be accessed later?** Or storing in root scope would be bad practice and I should consider some other option or nothing at all?
Would like to get some views on Angular Community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5I4FhdpPnq5Dpv3mlbh?p=preview) on how to use **factory** for  sharing data across the application.

Lets create a factory which can be used in entire application across all controllers to store data and access them.

Advantages with factory is you can create objects in it and intialise them any where in the controllers or we can set the defult values by intialising them in the factory itself.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('SharedData',['$http','$rootScope',function($http,$rootScope){

    var SharedData = {}; // create factory object...
    SharedData.appName ='My App';
    return SharedData;
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('Auth', ['$http', '$q', 'SharedData', function($http, $q,SharedData) {
   this.getUser = function() {

            return $http.get('user.json')
              .then(function(response) {
                  this.user = response.data;
                  SharedData.userData = this.user; // inject in the service and create a object in factory ob ject to store user data..
                  return response.data;
              }, function(error) {
                  return $q.reject(error.data);
              });

    };

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("testController", ["$scope",'SharedData','Auth',
  function($scope,SharedData,Auth) {

    $scope.user ={};
   // do a service call via service and check the shared data which is factory object ...
   var user = Auth.getUser().then(function(res){
       console.log(SharedData);
       $scope.user = SharedData.userData;// assigning to scope.
   });


  }]);
```

In HTML

```
<body ng-app='app'>
    <div class="media-list" ng-controller="testController">

       <pre> {{user | json}}</pre>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This looks good, but say in those rare cases user changes his/her details. How will I update the data? and make sure that factory gives us the same output even when the data is changed

Comment: That's not a problem you can just use `SharedData.userData` object to assign new values after user details updated or just by calling your `service.getUser();` the sharedData object will get updated.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zz6HXlGblygUNjEryvdI?p=preview here is the plunker explaining what I said above for your question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rootScope` just use a local variable of `user` in your service that can be accessed from anywhere in your code and so you doesn't have to call the api every time.

```
angular.module('metaiotAdmin').service('Auth', ['$http', '$q', 'Config', function($http, $q, Config) {
    this.getUser = function() {
        if(this.user){
            return this.user;
        }
        else{
            return $http.get(Config.apiurl + '/auth/user')
              .then(function(response) {
                  this.user = response.data;
                  return response.data;
              }, function(error) {
                  return $q.reject(error.data);
              });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks good. The lifetime of the `user` variable would be the time this application is open in the tab right?

Comment: Yes, like `rootscope` but the the recommended way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, $http already caches your request for you, if the same request is applied in case you set the cache config option to true.

```
$http.get('/hello', { cache: true})
      .then(onResponse)
```

or you can either set it for every request, by using either an interceptor or override the http instance in the $httpProvider, to apply the effect for every http request.

```
app.module('app.module')
    factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function() {
         return {
              request : function(config) {
                  config.cache = true;
                  return config;
              },
              // rest of implementation of the interceptor
         }

    }); 



app.module('app.module')
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
           // ... rest of the configuration
      }]);
```

Or :

```
app.module('app.module')
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
           // ...
     }]);
```

see :
[Angular doc for caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)

Comment: This looks good, but say in those rare cases user changes his/her details. Will `{cache : true}` will give us the same output even when the data is changed? How would that be handled?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it depends of your needs, maybe you should add a parameter to the service that is responsible of loading the user from your server. The parameter should enable/disable load from cache.
Say for example:
UserService.getUser(true).then( ...)
where the boolean is an option to decide weither laod from cache or not